# EF Core: The instance of entity type 'xxxx' cannot be tracked... Error when updating parent record by adding children

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, c#-11.0

I've run into a very peculiar error and would greatly appreciate help. I am currently working on a new winforms application using .net7. We are using EF core to integrate with a MS Acces DB file (no choice). I have built a service that queries an existing BusinessDate entity object, and then adds child OtcVariationMarginRecords to it. I have been solely working on this in unit and integration tests (XUnit). It is the integration tests where I am experiencing a problem: Up until a few days ago, the service worked flawlessly, saving all the records as expected in the DB file. Then two days ago, I started receiving this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'OtcVariationMarginRecord' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

What I've tried:

- We recently updated our Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package from 7.0.9 to 7.0.10. I tried rolling it back, but the issue persisted. Nothing else has changed recently.
- I created simple Parent/Child model objects with minimal properties, ran the migrations, and received the same error when trying update an existing parent by adding children. Thus the issue is not with my margin models.
- We inject a complicated _dbContextService wrapper/interface (not created by me) that handles all sorts of audit trail updating. I have completely removed it and instead reference the concrete dbContext. Did not fix.
- I am relatively new to EF core, so I read everything [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/). I tried shortening the life of the dbContext (see code below) but the same error returned.
- I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56545216/invalidoperationexception-the-instance-of-entity-cannot-be-tracked-ef-core), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176014/how-to-add-update-child-entities-when-updating-a-parent-entity-in-ef), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987635/the-instance-of-entity-type-item-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-wi). Using AsNoTracking() just results in no OtcVariationMarginRecord records being saved to the DB. Same with _context.ChangeTracker.Clear().

I feel absolutely stumped, and hope someone here can point out an obvious flaw in my code. Many thanks.

Entity models:

```
[Index(nameof(Date), IsUnique = true)]
public class BusinessDate : BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<OtcVariationMarginRecord> OtcVariationMarginRecords { get; set; } = new();
}

public class OtcVariationMarginRecord : BaseEntity
{   
    public decimal BaseCurrencyExposure { get; set; }
    public CurrencyCode BaseCurrency { get; set; }
    public decimal TransferAmount { get; set; }
    public MarginCallNature CallNature { get; set; }
    public MarginDirection Direction { get; set; }
    public decimal RoundedTransferAmount { get; set; }

    // i have removed a bunch of properties as part of my trouble shooting.
}
public abstract class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual RecordStatus Status { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string? LastModifiedByName { get; set; }
}
```

Simplified usage:

```
private EfCoreTrackingTestContext _context;

public async Task GenerateMarginRecordsAsync(DateTime asOfDate)
{
    // i instantiate here instead of inject just for troubleshooting
    await using (_context = InstantiateContext())
    {
        var businessDate = await _context
            .BusinessDates
            //.AsNoTracking() // this resulted in nothing being saved
            .Include(bd => bd.OtcVariationMarginRecords)            
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(bd => bd.Date == asOfDate)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        // nothing here touches the db nor entities that already exist
        var newMarginRecords = CalculationLogic();

        targetBusinessDate.OtcVariationMarginRecords.AddRange(newMarginRecords);
        
        // error thrown here
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);        
    }
}
private static EfCoreTrackingTestContext InstantiateContext()
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EfCoreTrackingTestContext>();
    var options = optionsBuilder
        .UseJet(TestDbConfig.ConnectionString.IntegrationTestMarginDb)
        .Options;
    return new EfCoreTrackingTestContext(options);
}
```

---

### Update 2023-08-31

Thanks for the replies everyone. The problem persists. I have been asked to post some of the calculation logic, thus I've included a simplified version below. Some other answers to questions:

- Q: Can you confirm whether it actually stopped working after upgrading the EF Core version, or might that have been a coincidental "around the same time"?
- A: I cannot confirm, I am treating it more as a clue. I believe I was able to run the integration tests successfully for a couple days following the update. Could be related, could be coincidental.

---

- Q: What provider are you using for the MSAccess connection?
- A: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;

---

- Q: in the Access database is the Id column in the OtcVariationMarginRecord table set to an Autonumber?
- A: Confirmed that it is.

---

- Q: Is that the actual table name, because if not, are there any OnModelCreating or IEntityTypeConfiguration implementations set up for configuring the entity to table relationship?
- A: The name of the table is OtcVariationMarginRecord**s**. I have included OnModelCreating code below.

---

Additionally, I have tried Fabio's suggestion, but I am still getting the same error.

Here is some more code:

```
private ICollection<OtcVariationMarginRecord>  CalculationLogic()
 {

    // Simplified for brevity. Removed all CRUD operations besides create, as that's 
    // what I've done during troubleshooting anyway.
    var toAdd = new List<OtcVariationMarginRecord>();

     // derived from raw data retrieved from vendor api (unrelated to internal db)
     IEnumerable<OtcMarginCounterparty> marginCounterparties = GetMarginCounterparties();
     // derived from raw data retrieved from vendor api (unrelated to internal db)
     IEnumerable<Trade> marginTrades = GetMarginTrades();
     // loop through all counterparties and check exposure against limits.
     foreach (var counterparty in marginCounterparties)
     {         
         var counterpartyTrades = marginTrades.Where(t => t.Counterparty == counterparty.Name);         
         var calculatedVm = Calculate(counterpartyTrades, counterparty);

         toAdd.Add(calculatedVm);
     }

     return toAdd;
 }
 private OtcVariationMarginRecord Calculate(
    IEnumerable<Trade> counterpartyTrades,
    OtcMarginCounterparty counterparty)
 {
    // basically just math here to determine decimal and enum values...

    return new OtcVariationMarginRecord
    {
        Direction = direction,
        CallNature = nature,
        TransferAmount = transferAmount,
        RoundedTransferAmount = roundedCallAmount,
        Status = RecordStatus.Pending,
        BaseCurrencyExposure = counterpartyExposureBaseCcy,
        BaseCurrency = portfolioCurrency
    };
 }
```

And code related to the migrations:

```
public class EfCoreTrackingTestContext : DbContext
{    
    public DbSet<BusinessDate> BusinessDates => Set<BusinessDate>();
    public DbSet<OtcVariationMarginRecord> OtcVariationMarginRecords => Set<OtcVariationMarginRecord>();

    public EfCoreTrackingTestContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
    {
        base.ConfigureConventions(configurationBuilder);
        configurationBuilder.Properties<string>().HaveMaxLength(255);
        configurationBuilder.Properties<decimal>().HaveColumnType("decimal(18, 2)");
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Make EF core not create a table for BaseEntity abstraction
        builder.Entity<BaseEntity>().UseTpcMappingStrategy();

        builder.Entity<BusinessDate>()
            .HasMany(s => s.OtcVariationMarginRecords)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);   
    }

}
```

---

### Second Update 2023-08-31

Continuing with the troubleshooting, I switched the DB from MS Access to Sql Express, updated my DbContextFactory accordingly, and created new migrations. After doing this, **all of my original code works**, meaning all CRUD operations work as expected and obviously no tracking errors. So clearly something is wrong with how I connect to MS Access via EF Core. I just cannot fathom what it is.

Comment: Did you insert same specific `id` on loop? Can you share the sample code of `CalculationLogic`?

Comment: Ensure that `CalculationLogic` returns records with `OtcVariationMarginRecord.Id` equal to `0`

Comment: I can confirm that `CalculationLogic` returns records with `OtcVariationMarginRecord.Id` equal to `0`. I'll work on sharing some code from `CalculationLogic`.

Comment: can you confirm whether it actually stopped working after upgrading the EF Core version, or might that have been a coincidental "around the same time"? What provider are you using for the MSAccess connection? in the Access database is the Id column in the OtcVariationMarginRecord  table set to an Autonumber? Is that the actual table name, because if not, are there any OnModelCreating or IEntityTypeConfiguration implementations set up for configuring the entity to table relationship?

Comment: I just posted an update with an answer to all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

The issue was caused by this:

```
// problem code 1
builder.Entity<BaseEntity>().UseTpcMappingStrategy();
```

In combination with using an integer as the primary key:

```
// problem code 2
public abstract class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#Key-generation).

Changing the strategy to [TPT](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore5.com/whats-new-in-ef-core-5/table-per-type-tpt-mapping) or changing the primary key dataType to Guid both resolve the issue. We opted to change all primary key dataTypes to Guid as that appears to be a more scalable standard anyway.

```
// updated code
public abstract class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the OtcVariationMarginRecord table, EF will automatically add the fields related to the FK Business Date (which is the parent table), because it's a child table. You can verify for yourself (I tried). It's better to modify the class, adding the FK, so we can reference to it, later in the code:

```
public class OtcVariationMarginRecord : BaseEntity
{
    public decimal BaseCurrencyExposure { get; set; }
    public CurrencyCode BaseCurrency { get; set; }
    public decimal TransferAmount { get; set; }
    public MargingCallNature CallNature { get; set; }
    public MargingDirection Direction { get; set; }
    public decimal RoundedTransferAmount { get; set; }
    public int BusinessDateId { get; set; }
    public BusinessDate BusinessDate { get; set; }           
}
```

Finally, You can try this code:

```
public async Task GenerateMarginRecordsAsync(DateTime asOfDate)
{                                                
    await using (_context = InstantiateContext())
    {
        var targetbusinessDate = await _context
            .BusinessDates                                            
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(bd => bd.Date == asOfDate)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        int myId = targetbusinessDate.Id;
        _context.Entry(targetbusinessDate).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

        var newMarginRecords = CalculationLogic();
      
        foreach (OtcVariationMarginRecord mr in newMarginRecords)
        {
            mr.Id = 0;
            mr.BusinessDateId = myId;
            _context.OtcVariationMarginRecords.Add(mr);
        }
                        
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

I added the new OtcVariationMarginRecords directly into their table, without including the existing ones in the parent table.
I hope, this will help You.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented your suggestion, but I am getting the same error message on SaveChangesAsync(). I have just upated my post to share more code.